# Why is this SQL statement failing? Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am running on Host Gator and using a mySQL backend, with phpMyAdmin as a GUI.

I am coding in PHP.

I have had no issues performing standard prepare statements, but all of a sudden, with my first delete statement, there seems to be an error.  I cannot spot or debug it.  The following code is where the error occurs.

```
    //Error occurs right here
    if(!($sql = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM quoteItems WHERE quoteID=?")))
    { echo "FAIL - Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ") " . $con->error;}

    if(!$sql->bind_param('i', $quoteID))
    {echo "FAIL - Binding parameters failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error;}

    if(!$sql->execute())
    {echo "FAIL - Execute failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error;}
```

The output of `var_dump($quoteID);` gives `string "44"` in my current situation.

The error message that is produced is `FAIL - Prepare failed:(0) Fatal Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object`

Comment: Do you have a parameter for the `?`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I do one line down.  I will update the details.

Comment: Is `$con` a valid mysqli object? Do you have `DELETE` rights for this db user?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It actually spits out more of an error after adding in the other lines (they were commented to narrow down) I've updated text above

Comment: That should not show a string and something is treating it as such rather than an integer. You can change that i for an s. but the column type needs to match

Comment: @Sean I believe Con is a valid object - But I did not have delete rights, as I initially didnt think i needed to delete anything! Thanks for the idea mate! That solved the issue.

Comment: @Sean you should make an answer here for this, and I will accept it as correct, as your comment fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was correctly solved by @Sean in the comments under the OP.

> Is $con a valid mysqli object? **Do you have DELETE rights for this db
>   user?**

The user did not have DELETE rights - giving the user this right solved the issue.  The $con object was a valid object.